# JavaScript submit form doesn't pass a hidden value correctly

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I want to pass a hidden value without using a submit button.
I want the user to click on an item image and it will bring them to the item detail.

So, if they click on the tomato shown below, it will bring them to the tomato page.

[image: tomato]

This is what I do:

jsp:

```
<form action="ItemDetail" method="get" name="itemForm" id="itemForm">
<input type="hidden" name="itemId" id="itemId" value="<%= i.getItemID() %>">
  <a href="javascript: submitForm()">
    <img src="<%=i.getImg()%>"
  </a>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
function submitForm(){
    document.forms["itemForm"].submit();
}
```

servlet:

```
String itemId = request.getParameter("itemId");
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that your rendered HTML correctly has the value of `itemId` set? Your form `action` is just `ItemDetail`. Is that a valid path to your .jsp? When you debug this and put a breakpoint on your servlet code, does it actually stop there? It's not really clear right now what issue you're having. Do you have JavaScript errors?

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Okay so I found the problem. Since I looped for the `<img>` tag, I have so many `<input type="hidden">` and when I use `getParameter` in Servlet, it only take the first loop. so now my question changed to how could I know which image was clicked so I can pass the correct parameter? I guess I should close this one and ask a new question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out why.
The javascript submit all the form because they all have the same name, so I changed the form id and make no changes to servlet

```
<form action="ItemDetail" method="get" name="itemForm" id="itemForm<%= i.getItemID() %>">
  <a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('itemForm<%= i.getItemID() %>').submit();">
  <input type="hidden" name="itemId" id="itemId" value="<%= i.getItemID() %>">

    <img src="<%=i.getImg()%>"
  </a>
</form>
```